# Buildroot ir remote using ir-keytable or lirc

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, buildroot, lirc

I created an image for raspberry pi zero 2 w using buildroot,

Also added overlay gpio-ir in config.txt but not able to receive ir signal.

No logs are printed for gpio in dmesg.

No devices are showing in /proc/bus/input/devices

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution my self.

Actually buildroot is not start gpio-ir-recv module at boot time.

So we need to load module manually at boot time.

We can load module by this command

```
modprobe gpio-ir-recv
```

So i have created one service to load module in /etc/init.d